# Javascript - Scriptaculous - Effect Callback function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am using scriptaculous to perform a slidedown effect using the following code:

```
Effect.SlideDown('dom_element_id');
```

I then hide the button which initiates this effect using:

```
$('button_id').hide();
```

The issue is that the button is hidden before the animation effect is complete, I would like it to hide after the animation effect is complete. I could not find a callback parameter for `Effect.SlideDown`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass the `afterFinish` option to pass a callback to be run after the effect has been completed.

```
Effect.SlideDown('dom_element_id', { afterFinish: function () {$('button_id').hide(); } } );
```

**EDIT**

Note that `beforeFinish`, `afterFinish`, `beforeSetup`, `afterSetup`, `beforeUpdate` and `afterUpdate` options can be used for any effects as they are part of `Effect.Base`.

[Also see the official docs here.](http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/core-effects/)

Comment: This answer saved me quite some time, thanks. Added the doc link to improve it further.